# looking for an argument to show the convergence in $\sum_n\frac{n!}{(en)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am looking for an argument why $\sum_n{(n/e)^n\over n!}$ is convergent.
This series appeared after I was looking for a radius in $\sum_n \frac{n^n}{n!}x^n$ and found, that it is between $-1/e$ and $1/e$. Now I am looking for an argument , why the first one is convergent and do not know what to do.
Thank you

Sorry, it was a wrong formula-it is otherway around.I tried to change it.Thank you for your help

Comment: Try quotient test.

Comment: @Eu2718 I formatted your summations in LaTeX.  Please check that this is what you intended.

Comment: The Stirling's approximation would probably help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation

Comment: Is Stirling also in this case usefull?

Comment: You have 10 questions, some of them with good answers. Please go ahead and accept those which you consider answered. You accept an answer by clicking on the grayed out hook under vote counter on the left of an answer. It will give you 2 reputation, a higher chance that future questions are answered and helps clearing the unanswered question list.

Comment: @Eu2718 did you intend to say that sum( n!/n^n x^n ) converges between x=-e and x=e instead of between -1/e and 1/e?

Comment: This user should accept *and upvote* more solutions to his questions.

Comment: The sum in the title is different from the sum in the question.

Comment: For sums use `\sum` not `\Sigma`.

Answer (score 1):

For points at the ends of the convergence interval, the quotient and root test fail exactly because they are the end points. In some cases the refined quotient tests that are called Raabe, Kummer or Gauß test will provide a definite answer. But theory says that for any test, however refined, there will always be undecidable cases.

---

The Raabe test requires the consideration of

$$n\left(\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|-1\right)=\frac{n}{e}\left((1+\tfrac1n)^n-e\right)$$

and this would need to have a bound smaller than $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stirlings approximation, you can replace $n!/n^n$ by $e^{-n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}$.
This reduces $\sum\frac{n!}{n^n} x^n $ to $\sum e^{-n} \sqrt{ 2 \pi n}\, x^n $, where obviously the convergence is limited to $|x|< e$.

For $x= +e (1-\varepsilon)$ the limit for $\varepsilon \to 0$ goes to infinity, but the case of $x= -e (1-\varepsilon)$ gives us a set of (ugly) limits for $\varepsilon\to0$ that depends on the approximation order used for Stirlings approximation.

Answer (score 0):

By Stirling, the general term of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(ne^{-1})^n}{n!}$$ is asymptotic to

$$\frac{(ne^{-1})^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(ne^{-1})^n}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}},$$ making the series diverge.